# Perl get the site path

Tags: perl, parsing, path

I want to knew how to parse the path from a site
ex :

```
http://example.org/hello/ok/fl.jpg
```

is there a way to parse this part (path)

```
/hello/ok/
```

Comment: you can use the URI module to parse a URL into it's component parts. Check it's documentation

Comment: The _path_ part of the given URI is `/hello/ok/fl.jpg`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org). The `path` method returns a [Mojo::Path](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Path) object that you can manipulate:

```
use Mojo::URL;
my $url = "http://example.org/hello/ok/fl.jpg";
say Mojo::URL->new( $url )->path->to_dir;
```

And here's [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI), which is the same at the start but returns the path as a string. You can get the segments then take off the last one. Replacing it with the empty string then `join`ing with the `/` gives you the trailing slash:

```
use URI;
my $url = "http://example.org/hello/ok/fl.jpg";
my @segments = URI->new( $url )->path_segments;
$segments[-1] = '';
say join '/', @segments;
```